# Android online dynamic database

Tags: android, database, storage

I am new to Android programming and I want to make an online database with information and pictures. In our case we are making app that stores recipes and their pictures. More recipes and pictures will be added in the future therefore it will use Internet to fetch data.

**Question:**

What is the best practice to store pictures - both old and new ones that will come in the future? On the database itself or on app? And does that mean if we add new recipes would consumer have to update the app if we store it on the app itself and not on web database?

Comment: I would say have local storage for offline use and synchronize it with online database, regarding picture, the same if user should have them locally then a local version and a cloud version. So regarding database you can use online service like GAE Google App Engine etc. OR you can build your Own Restful API connect to a hosted MySQL / some database, and regarding Cloud storage you need to find out Cloud storage provider, this is the way I do it. if you need i can formulate a more details answer with what I  have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my opinion the best practice would be keeping data and images on server and fetching it on real-time as per user need. As saving all images in application and updating more late on would increase the size of application.

You can create local database and cache for your images in which you can store data and images as user goes on accessing your application section, so that user can re-access those sections again in offline mode, but for new data user has to go online, you can instruct user where he would need internet access. Besides this you also need to specify some checkpoints in your flow where application should sync with cloud and update local data.